# Activate origami folding for python only with using use-package

Tags: python, use-package, code-folding

I want to activate `origami` folding mode for `python` only. I do use `use-package` for loading and configuring my packages.

This is what I tried so far

```
(use-package origami)

(use-package python
  :ensure nil  ; in-build!
  :hook
  (python-mode . origami-mode)
  :custom
  (python-shell-interpreter "python3")
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution work but I am not sure if this is the best solution. I still wonder if `:hook` should be the first choice and how this should be used.

Anyway it works when "moving" the hook into the `:config` section.

```
(use-package python
  :ensure nil  ; in-build!
  :config
  (add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'origami-mode)
  :custom
  (python-shell-interpreter "python3")
  )
```

Comment: A working solution beats a "better" non-working solution every time :-)

Answer (score 1):

[I don't know much about `use-package` and moreover I have not tested this. Try it if you want and let me know if it works: if it does not, I'll delete this answer.]

From reading the [Hooks section](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#hooks) in the GitHub README for `use-package`, I think the usage is that you have to add the hook section in the `use-package` declaration of the minor mode, not that of the major mode. IOW, you have to modify the `use-package` declaration of `origami` in order to add the `origami` minor mode to `python-mode`:

```el
(use-package origami
  :hook python-mode
  ...
)
```

Comment: Your solution looks definitly more the `use-package` way. It has an effect. But I got an error: `File mode specification error: (error Autoloading file /home/user/.emacs.d/elpa/origami-20200331.1019/origami.elc failed to define function origami)`. But I am able to do `M-x origami-mode`